# How to do multi-table aggregates using Spring Data repositories?

Tags: spring-data

What's the best approach for doing multi-table aggregates, or non aggregate multi table results in my Spring Data repositories. I don't care about mapping back to entities, I just need a list of objects returned I can massage into a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about entities, repositories are not the tool for the job. Repositories are defined to simulate collections of aggregates (which are special kinds of entities usually).

So to answer the question from your headline (which surprisingly seems to be the opposite of what you're asking in the description): just do it. Define your entity types including the relations that form the aggregate, create a repository for them and query it, define query methods etc.

If you don't care about types (which is perfectly fine, too), have a look at [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) which is centered around SQL to efficiently query relational databases, but wrapped into a nice API.

Comment: Hi, I have all the entity types defined and the repositories working for providing CRUD.  Its just for one particular javascript chart in my project, I need to do a straight SQL query across a few entities and get the aggregates back - but as there is no CRUD in this part (chart visualisation), mapping entities is not important...although I would like to have it my repository layer as that deals with all my EM stuff for me.